# displaying jqgrid in mvc3 after clicking on button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I'm building a simple mvc3 app using jqgrid.
My form currently calls a function in my controller that searches the database based on what the user has inputted into the textboxes after clicking on a search button.
I want to only display the jqgrid with the information after clicking on the search button.
Any idea on how to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an additional variable to the controller to check whether you have selected a button or not.

example:

```
('#grid').jqgrid({
...
url: '/Controller/Action/?additionalvariable = ' + variable,
...
)};
```

where the value of the variable is true or false depending on whether you have searched or not.